# I fancy myself an amateur lawyer. Can I represent someone in court, in the state of Maryland?

Tags: united-states, maryland, unlicensed-practice, legal-representation

I live in Montgomery County Maryland. I am not a lawyer.

But I have significant legal experience. I have successfully sued people, watched many trials, I have successfully won dozens of trials for my own traffic violations. And I'm a former state legislator. So I have read and argued about lots of legislation. Sometimes I feel like an amateur lawyer myself. And a pretty darn good one at that.

My father recently received a ticket from an automated-traffic-enforcement system because he made a right turn without coming to a full stop. The fine is $75. But he doesn't want to pay it and I don't want him to pay it. It's more the principle of the matter than the fine amount.

Because of my extensive experience litigating traffic trials, I want to represent my father in his trial. But as I mentioned above, I am not a licensed attorney. Can I represent him nonetheless? When the judge goes through the docket and calls his case, can I stand up and say, "Your Honor, I'm here representing Mr. Ali in this case?" Or will I get in trouble for doing so?

This case is in the District Court of Maryland in Montgomery County.

Comment: Some English law jurisdictions allow "friends": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McKenzie_friend

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85201/discussion-on-question-by-saqib-ali-i-fancy-myself-an-amateur-lawyer-can-i-repr).

Comment: A good amatuer attorney with "extensive legal experience" would be able to look this up.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If you are not a member of the Bar of Maryland, you may not "practice, attempt to practice, or offer to practice law in the State unless admitted to the Bar." [Maryland Business Occupations and Professions § 10-601](https://law.justia.com/codes/maryland/2005/gbo/10-601.html).

"Practicing law" includes "representing another person before a unit of the State government or of a political subdivision." [Maryland Business Occupations and Professions § 10-101](https://law.justia.com/codes/maryland/2005/gbo/10-101.html).

"[A] person who violates § 10-601 of this subtitle is guilty of a misdemeanor and on conviction is subject to a fine not exceeding $5,000 or imprisonment not exceeding 1 year or both." [Maryland Business Occupations and Professions § 10-606](https://law.justia.com/codes/maryland/2005/gbo/10-606.html).

EDIT: Because it's coming up in the comments I'll add that the option of a "McKenzie friend" is unavailable in Maryland and in the United States generally. There are [some jurisdictions](https://www.wsba.org/for-legal-professionals/join-the-legal-profession-in-wa/limited-license-legal-technicians/become-a-legal-technician) (404. [Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20191124234802/http://www.wsba.org:80/for-legal-professionals/join-the-legal-profession-in-wa/limited-license-legal-technicians/become-a-legal-technician). ) experimenting with limited representation by non-lawyers, but I don't know of any such moves in Maryland.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99269/discussion-on-answer-by-bdb484-i-fancy-myself-an-amateur-lawyer-can-i-represent).

Comment: What is proposed in the question isn't remotely like a McKenzie friend. You probably could be a McKenzie friend in Maryland despite the lack of formal statutes or rules or cases authorizing it. But a McKenzie friend is basically an emotional support person and secretary, not a litigator on someone else's behalf. It isn't limited practice of law like states including Colorado are now authorizing.